# Python 2.6: Creating image from array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Python rookie here! So, I have a data file which stores a list of bytes, representing pixel values in an image. I know that the image is 3-by-3 pixels. Here's my code so far:

```
# Part 1: read the data
data = []
file = open("test.dat", "rb")
for i in range(0, 9)
    byte = file.read(1)
    data[i] = byte
file.close()

# Part2: create the image
image = PIL.Image.frombytes('L', (3, 3), data)
image.save('image.bmp')
```

I have a couple of questions:

In part 1, is this the best way to read a binary file and store the data in an array?

In part 2, I get the error "TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not list.

Any help on either of these?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this your actual code? `for i=1:9` doesn't look like Python to me.

Comment: Oh sorry - I was thinking of Matlab. It's fixed now!

Comment: I found a question and answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759637/python-pil-bytes-to-image it may help show what you need. Your list build should be data.append(byte), but your part 2 error comment says that you should not build it as a list anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Part 1

If you know that you need exactly nine bytes of data, that looks like a fine way to do it, though it would probably be cleaner/clearer to use a context manager and skip the explicit loop:

```
with open('test.dat', 'rb') as infile:
    data = list(infile.read(9)) # read nine bytes and convert to a list
```

### Part 2

[According to the documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes), the data you must pass to `PIL.Image.frombytes` is:

> data – A byte buffer containing raw data for the given mode.

A list isn't a byte buffer, so you're probably wasting your time converting the input to a list. My **guess** is that if you pass it the byte string directly, you'll get what you're looking for. This is what I'd try:

```
with open('test.dat', 'rb') as infile:
    data = infile.read(9) # Don't convert the bytestring to a list
image = PIL.Image.frombytes('L', (3, 3), data) # pass in the bytestring
image.save('image.bmp')
```

Hopefully that helps; obviously I can't test it over here since I don't know what the content of your file is.

Of course, if you really need the bytes as a list for some other reason (doubtful--you can iterate over a string just as well as a list), you can always either convert them to a list when you need it (`datalist = list(data)`) or join them into a string when you make the call to `PIL`:

```
image = PIL.Image.frombytes('L', (3, 3), ''.join(datalist))
```

### Part 3

This is sort of an aside, but it's likely to be relevant: do you know what version of `PIL` you're using? If you're using the actual, original Python Imaging Library, you may also be running into some of the many problems with that library--it's super buggy and unsupported since about 2009.

If you are, I *highly* recommend getting rid of it and grabbing the [Pillow fork](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) instead, which is the live, functional version. You don't have to change any code (it still installs a module called `PIL`), but the Pillow library is superior to the original `PIL` by leaps and bounds.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help!

Comment: it might help someone - I had to add "from PIL import Image" for using the Image directly (for example: Image.frombytes(...) )

Comment: Is this approach only intended for bytestrings that include an image header? I am trying to create bitmaps from bytestrings that do not have an image header and I cannot open the resulting files.