# Generate pixel image in Python from array

Tags: python, image-processing, rgb, pixel

I'm trying to figure out different ways to visualize data and how to get a grasp on image processing.

[Python 2.6: Creating image from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019678/python-2-6-creating-image-from-array) seems to be doing something different

I thought for a simple example, I could create an image from scratch that varies in pixel intensity.  I use the `A_pixelIntensity` array to declare the intensities of pixel colors.  I then do a transformation in the `create_pixel_gradient` function to make the higher intensity pixels darker and the lower intensity pixels whiter.

How can I view this image? Is `matplotlib.pyplot` the best way? What about `PIL.Image` and `iPython.display`?

```
import numpy as np
#Intensity of Image
A_pixelIntensity = np.asarray([[1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,2,2,1],[1,2,3,2,1],[1,2,2,2,1],[1,1,1,1,1]])
# [[1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 2 2 2 1]
#  [1 2 3 2 1]
#  [1 2 2 2 1]
#  [1 1 1 1 1]]

#Color of Image
def create_pixel_gradient(A_intensity):
    maximum = np.amax(A_intensity)
    init = np.zeros(A_intensity.shape,dtype=tuple) #Create empty array to populate
    for i in range(A_intensity.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A_intensity.shape[1]):
            pixel_intensity = A_intensity[i,j] #Get original pixel intensities
            value = 255 - int(pixel_intensity*(255/np.amax(A_intensity))) #Lower intensities are more white (creates a gradient)
            init[i,j] = (value,255,value) #Populate array with RGB values
    return(init)

create_pixel_gradient(A_pixelIntensity)
# array([[(170, 255, 170), (170, 255, 170), (170, 255, 170), (170, 255, 170),
#         (170, 255, 170)],
#        [(170, 255, 170), (85, 255, 85), (85, 255, 85), (85, 255, 85),
#         (170, 255, 170)],
#        [(170, 255, 170), (85, 255, 85), (0, 255, 0), (85, 255, 85),
#         (170, 255, 170)],
#        [(170, 255, 170), (85, 255, 85), (85, 255, 85), (85, 255, 85),
#         (170, 255, 170)],
#        [(170, 255, 170), (170, 255, 170), (170, 255, 170), (170, 255, 170),
#         (170, 255, 170)]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A_pixelIntensity = np.asarray([[1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,2,2,1],[1,2,3,2,1],[1,2,2,2,1],[1,1,1,1,1]])

plt.imshow(A_pixelIntensity)
```

[image]